# what should be used to close ftp session, close or quit?

Tags: sockets, ftp

what should be used to close ftp session, close or quit?

Example:

1. upload file to server
2. close/quit ftp session

Server could check, if socket is closed during file uploading, than file is corrupted and removes it.

It seems, 'quit' is more reliable method, as it closes session on protocol level and 'close' terminates connection by socket level.

Am I right or both methods do the same?

Comment: i thought the difference was http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/Internet/node117.html - are you sure we're talking about the same "close"?

Comment: yes, the same. It looks like, 'close' is better, because connection is reusable in this case.

Comment: actually, both will close the connection. the difference is that one closes the ftp session and the other does not. Notice that ftp session != ftp connection